# PHP & JSON - Trouble to print a value on client side

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this PHP function :

```
if(($_POST['id']=="pm_read") && (isset($_POST['pm_id'])) && (ctype_digit($_POST['pm_id'])) && (isset($_SESSION['nickname']))) {
    $update=mysql_query("UPDATE pm SET readed='1' WHERE id='".$_POST['pm_id']."' AND receiver='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'",$mydb);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM pm WHERE receiver='".$_SESSION['nickname']."' AND readed='0' AND receiver_delete='0' ORDER by date DESC",$mydb);
    $arrayPm[0]=mysql_result($query,0,'COUNT(id)');
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT message FROM pm WHERE id='".$_POST['pm_id']."' AND receiver='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'",$mydb);     
    $arrayPm[1]=mysql_result($query,0,'message');
    echo json_encode($arrayPm);     
}
```

On client side, I get this array trought a jQuery function :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: 'pm/pm_ajax.php',
    data: 'pm_id='+$(this).attr('id')+'&id=pm_read',
    success: function(data) {
       ... here I'll print somethings...
    }
});
```

Unfortunatly, if I print `data` I get (for example) the string **["2", "message"]**.
So, if I try to do **alert(data[0])** I'll see only **[**.

How can I access to this array printing the correct result? I mean :

data[0] must print **2** and data[1] must print **message**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding

```
dataType:'json'
```

to your options in the ajax call.

Comment: Damn...my fault! I forgot it! Hehehe thanks and sorry for your time! :)

Answer (score 3):

Never insert unfiltered $_POST superglobal into mysql_queries. That's a security flaw.

Obviously data is being returned as a string, so data[0] is the first character. Instead you want JSON. So make sure you use header() in PHP, to set content-type: application/json

So give this a try before you echo your output:

```
header('content-type: application/json');
```

Also make sure your jquery request has

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: `Never insert unfiltered $_POST superglobal into mysql_queries. That's a security flaw.`. Is filtered man! The only $_POST I use is `$_POST['pm_id']`, and i check if its ctype_digit. So no trouble with SQL_Injection or other vulnerability, isnt it? :) About JSON : yes, I resolved by using dataType: json ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(obj[0]);
```